# Can Processing code in java run outside of the processing ide as a gui application?

Tags: java, processing, p5.js

I am talking about p5.js equivalent in java called `Processing` using which i can program a lot of graphical elements and it has event handling capabilities.

I have written my java code inside the processin ide . But i want this to work as a standalone gui application. Is this doable ? If so how ?

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/exporting-applications) is a guide on exporting Processing sketches.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the easiest way is to use Menu->File->Export-Application from the Processing app to generate a stand-alone executable for your platform.